# Training data in two steps with same accuracy?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, parallel-processing, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement active learning machine(an experiment for a project) algorithm, where I want to train separately, please check my code below.

```
clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(X_train[0:40], y_train[0:40])
clf.fit(X_train[40:], y_train[40:])
```

The above usually done like this

```
clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Both have different accuracy score. I want to add training data to existing model itself since its computationally expensive - I don't want my model to do one more time computation.

Any way I can ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called online training or Incremental learning used for large data. Please see this [page for strategies](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html).

Essentially, in scikit-learn, you need `partial_fit()` with all the labels in `y` known in advance.

> partial_fit(X, y, classes=None, sample_weight=None)
>
> ```
> classes : array-like, shape = [n_classes] (default=None)
> ```
>
> List of all the classes that can possibly appear in the y vector. Must be provided at the first call to partial_fit, can be omitted in subsequent calls.

If you simply do this:

```
clf.partial_fit(X_train[0:40], y_train[0:40])
clf.partial_fit(X_train[40:], y_train[40:])
```

Then there is a possibility that that if any class which is not present in the first 40 samples, and comes in next iterations of partial_fit(), then it will throw an error.

So ideally you should be doing this:

```
# First call
clf.partial_fit(X_train[0:40], y_train[0:40], classes = np.unique(y_train))

# subsequent calls
clf.partial_fit(X_train[40:80], y_train[40:80])
clf.partial_fit(X_train[80:], y_train[80:])

and so on..
```

Comment: accepting this answer since it has a more clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use partial_fit to train your model in batches.

```
clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.partial_fit(X_train[0:40], y_train[0:40])
clf.partial_fit(X_train[40:], y_train[40:])
```

Please check [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.partial_fit) to know more about the function.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: above worked perfect. Just waiting for some time(2days) before accept this answer. Thank you so much.